# If f is continuous, prove $h(x)=d(x,f(x))$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

I'm trying to prove that if $f:X\to X$ is continuous, then, $h:X\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x)=d(x,f(x))$ is continuous. I want to show there exists $r>0,$ such that if $\forall p\in X,$ d$(p,x)<r,$ we have $|d(p,f(p))-d(x,f(x))|<\epsilon.$ How do I continue?

Answer (score 1):

By continuity of $f$
$$(x_n)\to x\Rightarrow f(x_n)\to f(x)$$ for all convergent sequence. Hence in the product space (because of its standard topology) $$(x_n,f(x_n))\to (x,f(x))$$
Thus, by continuity of the metric $d$ we have $$d(x_n,f(x_n))\to d(x,f(x))$$ This shows the continuity of $h(x)=d(x,f(x))$

Comment: what does $\to$ mean?

Comment: In several post here I have seen this symbol meaning "convergent to"